# How to do this Sum? Poisson Resummation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In the paper [hep-th/0812.2909](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.2909) page 34-35, there's a sum that I've been trying to do explicitly but I can't find a way. The sum is

$$
\frac{2l}{\pi l! (l-1)!} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-i (2n+l+1)t+i k (\phi-t) } \frac{\Gamma(n+|k|+l+1)\Gamma(n+l+1)}{\Gamma(n+|k|+1)\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{l^{2}/(2^{l}\pi)}{[\cos(t-i\epsilon)-\cos(\phi))]^{l+1}}
$$

In page 54 the authors need again to do a similar sum(it's actually the same), where they say you have to use something called "Poisson Ressumation" and "sum over the images". I tried to use what i found about Poisson ressumation, but I don't know how to Fourier transform a quotient between gammas, and even if I did, I understand it would turn the left hand side into another sum over integers.

Thanks for your help!

PS: I'm not a native speaker so forgive me if my English is a bit rusty.

Comment: Where did the $\epsilon$ come from in the RHS?

Comment: @user7530 $\epsilon$ is a small quantity, ie $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, that exists around the poles in qft (quantum field theory) calculations.

Comment: I'm sorry i din't notice the answers before. As the user above said, it appears to avoid the singularities when one integrates (in this case... i guess the author turns somehow the sums to an integral... but I still don't know how or why).

Answer (score 0):

I am the OP, but just to put this to rest I solved this problem some years ago in App. A of https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.10306

Hope it saves time to someone!

Comment: Please edit the post, if you are the OP.  Link only answers are not appropriate.